# In React, why useState(foo()) call foo in every rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In React I know next code call foo one time in mount

```
(...)
function foo() {
 return {
      id: 1,
      text: 'hello',
    }
}

const App = () => {
  const [value, setter] = useState(foo);
(...)
```

but if I change the foo(useState's argument) to foo() this code call foo if App is rerendering.

I know the difference Between foo and foo() but I know why the difference is occur

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code `first(second())` means to call `second`, and pass its result into `first`. So every time a line like this runs, `second` will be called. Swap in the names in your code and we get `useState(foo())`, and it behaves the same. Every time this line runs, `foo` will be called.

As for why the other version only calls it once, that's because the `useState` hook is designed so that it if it receives a function, it will call that function on the first render only. On subsequent renders, you will still pass the function in, but react sees that this isn't the first render and so it does not call your function.

Answer (score 4):

Function calls in a function body must be evaluated by the JS engine, it doesn't know that React is going to ignore the result on subsequent renders.

It's just like any other function call in the control flow. It has to be evaluated before JS can call useState.

If you send the function reference instead, the implementation of useState knows only to evaluate it on mount.